# Rationale behind Instant.getEpochSecond vs Instant.toEpochMilli

Tags: java, java-time

Can somebody explain the rationale behind the naming of [Instant.getEpochSecond](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#getEpochSecond--) vs. [Instant.toEpochMilli](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli--)? The only reason I can think of is the internal representation of an instant as seconds relative to epoch and nano seconds relative to that second whereas the milli seconds are calculated from those two values.

But why would you let such an implementation detail leak into a new API?

Comment: This question is not opinion based as there are clear naming guidelines as Thomas already stated in his answer. See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd have to guess but I'd agree with you:

- `getEpochSecond()` indicates a mere getter, i.e. it just returns the value which is stored in that instance
- `toEpochMilli()` on the other hand would calculate its return value, much like `toString()` would not return a stored string but build in on-the-fly every time the method is called

That convention actually is documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html

The reason for this convention probably is related to the JavaBeans specification, i.e. `epochSecond` would be a (readonly) property of `Instant` whereas `epochMilli` is a different representation but not a property.

Comment: +1 for the link. Interestingly, `LocalDate` has a method `toEpochDay`, but also supports `getLong(ChronoField.EPOCH_DAY)`. So I'm still confused...

Comment: @isnot2bad `toEpochDay()` would do a conversion and thus the `toX()` naming is correct. `getLong()` on the other hand would return part of LocalDate's state in most cases, except for `getLong( EPOCH_DAY )` which actually results in the line `return toEpochDay();`. So I guess neither of both conventions perfectly fit here but the `getX()` convention would fit in most cases so I guess it's a compromise.

Comment: Possibly. Even more interesting is `LocalDateTime.toLocalDate()`. In my opinion, the local date is a part of `LocalDateTime`, hence `getLocalDate()` would fit better as it is not a conversion. Especially, as the javadoc says: _Gets the `LocalDate` part of this date-time._ ... ;)

Comment: @isnot2bad that's true, `toLocalDate()` is a pure getter. Well, I guess we can't expect the Oracle folks to be perfect ;)

Comment: Just to note that while `toLocalDate()` is implemented as a simple instance variable return today, there should be nothing in the spec that requires that. ie. the spec allows an implementation of `LocalDateTime` that directly holding primitive year+month+day+hour+min+sec+nano (instead of LocalDate+LocalTime), and creating a `LocalDate` instance when the method is called.

Answer (score 4):

The getters return parts of an `Temporal` object (like `Instant`), while the `to*` methods return a converted version of it:

- `getEpochSecond()` returns the gets the number of seconds from the Java epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
- `getNanos()` returns the nanoseconds-of-second-part of the `Instant`
- `toEpochMilli()` returns the `Instant` converted into milliseconds (i.e. `seconds * 1000 + nanoseconds / 1,000,000`)

Comment: Your answer seems to be incorrect. According to the javadoc `getEpochSecond()` gets the number of seconds from the Java epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. It is not seconds-part of the `Instant`.

Comment: @humbaba you're right, "seconds-part" is not very exact. I'm going to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Convenience? 
EpochSeconds for UNIX time compatibility, EpochMilli for java Date compatibility, from the top of my head.

Edit:
Oh, I didn't even understand the question, which is why one is a "get" and the other is a "to": maybe to remind you the second one does a conversion and might fail.